# Merging tag synonyms with main tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been looking through the tag wiki recently, and found in pages 8-12, there are many tags which have no definitions. Most of them are tag synonyms, but can they instead be merged with the main tags, and simply listed as tag synonyms in the main tag's labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense, and somebody proposed it *almost ten years ago*: [Display tag synonyms differently in the tag browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64750/295232). It's something which needs to be changed on a network-wide level.